# How to configure Proxy Host and Proxy Port during TransportClient creation in Elasticsearch in Spring Boot

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am using ElasticSearch TransportClient. I want to add Proxy information while TransportClient configuration:
Please file below my TransportClient configuration

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", cluster).put("node.name", node).build();
        TransportClient transportClient = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();

transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(hostname.trim()), port));
```

How to configure Proxy Host and Port?